# Flowers that grow in wine glass bottles filled with soil and/or water?

Tags: flowers, indoors, water

What flowers would be able to grow inside of a  glass bottle filled with water?

The glass bottle can also be filled with some soil, but they would need to grow in the bottle.

We live in the Caribbean, so it's extremely hot.

Comment: As the previous comment implies, cut flowers don't grow in vases, glass or otherwise, they are simply displayed in them because they need water. The flowers will have been grown in soil, then cut for sale.

Answer (score 1):

Spiderwort can be grown in a sealed bottle, [here](http://reekoscience.com/science-news/plants-science-news/garden-in-sealed-bottle-has-not-been-watered-in-over-40-years) an example of 40 years in a sealed bottle!!